# Show all records when current user is admin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have the following. How best to refactor it:

```
  def self.search(search, organization_id, is_admin)
    if is_admin == false
      where("record_no LIKE ?", "%#{search}%").
        where("organization_id = ?", organization_id)
    else
      where("record_no LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
    end
  end
```

Basically this means, I want it to show all records without the `organization_id` when user is an admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About your code:

- The argument name `search` is confusing (the same as the method), use instead the value it stands for: `record_no`.
- `"record_no LIKE ?"`. This is perfectly fine, but, if you used [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) instead, the query would work for all database.
- `if is_admin == false` -> `if !is_admin` or `unless is_admin`. Shorter, more declarative, idiomatic.
- DRY your code by reusing the repeated scope.
- `organization_id`: Since you using anORM, you usually send objects as arguments, not their IDs. Does it make sense for you code?
- `where("organization_id = ?", organization_id)`. Use a hash instead.

I'd write:

```
def self.search(record_no, organization_id, is_admin)
  with_record_no = where(arel_table[:record_no].matches("%#{record_no}%"))
  if is_admin
    with_record_no
  else
    with_record_no.where(organization_id: organization_id)
  end 
end
```

Comment: Is sending id instead of object, a bad practice? What if the object is huge?

Comment: "Sending" an object is not a problem, you are passing a reference. The thing is: if you have the object already instantiated when you call this method or you have just the ID. Then you decide which signature to use.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
def self.search(search, organization_id, is_admin)
  # Avoids repetition of this query. Take note that Rails doesn't hit
  # the database until hits an iterator or other non-AR method
  records = where("record_no LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")

  # if the user is admin we could return the records
  return records if is_admin

  # Adding more conditions to the query when the user is not admin
  records.where(organization_id: organization_id)
end
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan thank you for pointing out. I've added some comments

Comment: Great! Just to mention, it's often more readable to have the notes not just as comments in the code but rather plain text in between the code you're demonstrating.